# Making partition with unallocated disk space

Tags: partitioning

I have a default ubuntu 16.04 install.

My main drive is partitioned as follows:

```
sdb                            8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sdb1                         8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2                         8:18   0   488M  0 part /boot
└─sdb3                         8:19   0 231.9G  0 part
  ├─ikoda--yellow--vg-root   252:0    0  53.7G  0 lvm  /
  └─ikoda--yellow--vg-swap_1 252:1    0  15.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

So I am assuming there is around around 160GB of space as yet unallocated.

How do I create a partition with this space (preferably from the command line rather than Gparted)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check that free space using the command `vgs`. It should show you that approximately those 160G are free within a volume group.

I guess what you really want here instead of a new partition is a new logical volume, since all the free space you are talking about is managed by the Logical Volume Manager (lvm) in your case. You can create one using a command like this:

```
lvcreate -L 20G -n myvolume ikoda-yellow-vg
```

This will create a new logical volume named *myvolume* in the ikoda-yellow-vg volume group, with a size of 20GB.

After lvcreate you will be able to use the new volume (for e. g. formatting with a file system) under the name `/dev/ikoda-yellow-vg/myvolume`.